# Accept не работает со структурой подключенного клиента

Tags: c++, сервер, tcp

Когда клиент подключается к серверу и при этом в accept указана структура для заполнения информацией о клиенте, accept() выдает -1, хотя типы параметров учтены. Проблема пропадает когда передаю параметрами,заместь структуры, NULL,но при этом сервер не читает и не отсылает сообщения в ответ. Прошу помощи!
Вот код

'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
bool SetSocket(int &fd);
bool SetBind(int fd,sockaddr_in &sock);
bool StartListen(int fd);
bool SetAccept(int &fd,sockaddr_in &sock);
bool WhoIsClient(sockaddr_in &sock);

int main()
{
  int serv_socket;
  sockaddr_in serv;
  memset(&serv,0,sizeof(serv));
  serv.sin_addr.s_addr =htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serv.sin_family = PF_INET;
  serv.sin_port = htons(1234);
 SetSocket(serv_socket);
 SetBind(serv_socket,serv);
 StartListen(serv_socket);
 SetAccept(serv_socket,serv);
 close(serv_socket);
 return 0;
}
bool SetSocket(int &fd)
{
 if( (fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0 )
  {
    cerr<<"Can't open socket"<<endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
bool SetBind(int fd,sockaddr_in &sock)
{
 if( (bind(fd,(sockaddr*)&sock,sizeof(sock))) < 0 )
   {
    cerr<<"Can't bind the socket"<<endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
 bool StartListen(int fd)
{
 if ( listen(fd,10) < 0 )
   {
     cerr<<"Can't listen the port"<<endl;
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
 }
 bool SetAccept(int &fd,sockaddr_in &sock)
{
 int client_connect;
 sockaddr_in client;
 char msg[40];
 //structures for get name of host
   if ((client_connect = accept(fd,(sockaddr*)&client,     (socklen_t*)sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0 ))
     cout<< "Can't accept the queue of clients"<<endl;
 while(true)
 {
     if ( (recv(fd,msg,39,0)) > 0 )
       {
         WhoIsClient(client);
         cout<<"Msg:"<<msg<<endl;
       }
     if (strcmp(msg,"bye") == 0)
         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
     memset(msg,0,40);
     //inputting the message for client
     cout<<"Input the message for client"<<endl;
    // cin.getline(msg,39);
     //end of get msg

     if ( send(client_connect,msg,40,0) < 0 )
         cerr<<"Fail!!! can't send the message"<<endl;
  }
  close(client_connect);
}
 bool WhoIsClient(sockaddr_in &sock)
{
 struct hostent *hp;
 cout<<"New connection"<<endl;
 cout<<"Time: "<<ctime(0)<<endl;
 cout<<"IP: "<<inet_ntoa(sock.sin_addr)<<endl;
 hp =gethostbyaddr((constvoid*)&sock.sin_addr,sizeof(sock.sin_addr),AF_INET);
 cout<<"Name of user: "<<hp->h_name<<endl;
}`
```

Comment: А что это (socklen_t*)sizeof(sockaddr) такое?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow   это требование компилятора,чтобы тип длины выражался не ввиде int,а ввиде socklen_t*.

Comment: У компилятора нет таких требований. Это может быть требованием прототипа функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю, как выглядит объявление функции `accept`, но, думаю, третий аргумент в ее вызове указан неверно

```
accept(fd,(sockaddr*)&client,     (socklen_t*)sizeof(sockaddr) )
```

Похоже, что требуется указатель на объект, содержащий размер передаваемого буфера. Поэтому по крайней мере следует написать

```
sockaddr_in client;
socklen_t size = sizeof(sockaddr);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if ((client_connect = accept(fd,(sockaddr*)&client,  &size ) < 0 ))
                                                     ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо,вы правы...

Answer (score 1):

Третьим аргументом `accept()` д.б. адрес переменной типа socklen_t, **содержащей правильное значение**.

```
 socklen_t size = sizeof(client);
 if ((client_connect = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client,  &size )) < 0) ...
```

Обратите внимание на строки в `man 2 accept`

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller  must  initialize  it  to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to
>          by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address.